# Replacing a list within json file in python

Tags: python, json

I am working on a program that flips annotations on images horizontally. The annotation file is a json file that contains the coordinates of the points drawn on an image as lists. E.g

`{"filename":"262.JPG","size":299425,"regions":[{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[255,293,293,255],"all_points_y":[559,561,593,592]}...`

you can see my code here:

```
annotations = list(annotations.values())  # don't need the dict keys
annotations = [a for a in annotations if a['regions']]
print(type(annotations))
i=0

for a in annotations:
    # Get the x, y coordinaets of points of the polygons that make up
    # the outline of each object instance.
    polygons = [r['shape_attributes'] for r in a['regions']]
    print(len(polygons))

    for p in polygons:
        i+=1

        all_x = p["all_points_x"]

        print("all_x"+"_"+str(i),all_x)

        all_x_flip = []
        for x in all_x:
            # image width = 1228 pixel
            x = 1228 - x - 1
            all_x_flip.append(x)
        for r in a["regions"]:
            # if len(all_x )== len(all_x_flip):

            r["shape_attributes"]["all_points_x"] = all_x_flip
            print("flipped "+"_"+str(i),r["shape_attributes"]["all_points_x"])
            break

with open('262_flip_0.json', 'w') as file:
    print("writing json file")
    json.dump(annotations, file, separators=(',', ':'))
```

When executing it prints the lists in the right order

```
all_x_1 [255, 293, 293, 255]
flipped _1 [972, 934, 934, 972]
all_x_2 [350, 359, 364, 363, 354, 350]
flipped _2 [877, 868, 863, 864, 873, 877]
all_x_3 [577, 593, 594, 583, 577]
flipped _3 [650, 634, 633, 644, 650]
all_x_4 [809, 801, 801, 804, 816, 817]
flipped _4 [418, 426, 426, 423, 411, 410]
all_x_5 [771, 780, 777, 771]
flipped _5 [456, 447, 450, 456]
```

but my problem is writing those lists(flipped) into a json file. the new json file replaces the last list being generated in the forloop with the first list in the original json file and the other lists stay as are.

I tried to change my for loops in many different ways with no success...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here

```
for r in a["regions"]:
        # if len(all_x )== len(all_x_flip):

        r["shape_attributes"]["all_points_x"] = all_x_flip
        print("flipped "+"_"+str(i),r["shape_attributes"]["all_points_x"])
        break
```

Because you are doing again the iteration and updating always the first element in the list (in fact there is a break a the end)

You need something like:

```
for a in annotations:
    for curr_polygon in a["regions"]:
        p = curr_polygon['shape_attributes']
        i+=1
        all_x = p["all_points_x"]
        print("all_x"+"_"+str(i),all_x)
        all_x_flip = []
        for x in all_x:
            # image width = 1228 pixel
            x = 1228 - x - 1
            all_x_flip.append(x)
        curr_polygon["shape_attributes"]["all_points_x"] = all_x_flip
```